# add multiple SPList to SPListItemCollection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

I have 1 SPList to 1 SPListItemCollection , I want to add two SPList to 1 SPListItemCollection

1

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[Constants.ListNames.Name];
SPListItemCollection allItems = list.GetItems(spQuery);
```

2

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[Constants.ListNames.Name];
SPList list2 = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[Constants.ListNames.Name2];
    SPListItemCollection allItems = list.GetItems(spQuery);
allItems???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always like to use List<> to handle these. To do that, make sure you add

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then

```
List<SPListItem> allItems = new List<SPListItem>();
allItems.AddRange(list.GetItems(spQuery).Cast<SPListItem>().ToList());
allItems.AddRange(list2.GetItems(spQuery).Cast<SPListItem>().ToList());

//Do something to the "allItems"
```

That's it